# CMD-Period unexpectedly translated to ESC in IDEA apps on macos (PyCharm, GoLand, Android Studio)

Tags: macos, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide, goland

I use `Cmd-.` (Command-Period) as a common hotkey in my IDEs (go to definition), but recently the IDEA/JetBrains IDEs have started to re-interpret this key combination as the escape key. I can't figure out what exactly changed on my system to make this start happening. There was probably an OSX update or two which happened between the last time it worked and when I noticed the new behavior.

In the IDEA keymap menus, when I hit `Cmd-.` in the search-by-key dialog, it inserts the `Esc` glyph, the the behavior of the rest of the app seems to follow suit, it's just acting like `Esc`.

This issue seems to be specific to the IDEA-based apps. It reproduces in PyCharm, GoLand, and Android Studio. `Cmd-.` still works as expected in iTerm2, Cocoa Emacs, and the OSX system shortcut settings window.

Any idea of how I can bring back `Cmd-.`, or at least interpret it as something other than `Esc`?

Comment: Command-. is a long-standing Mac standard for "cancel". Escape is, too (although not *as* long-standing). I assume some developer for IDEA/JetBrains thought the best way to support the former is to map it (apparently at some low level within the app's event handling) to the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way to stop interpreting `Cmd-.` as `Esc`. However, as a workaround, you can try assigning the shortcut in a keymap XML file.

It may help in some cases, e.g. it works for opening tool windows, but it doesn’t work with Find in Path because sometimes the dialog gets closed (both `meta .` and `Esc` are invoked).

1. In `Preferences | Keymap`, set *some* shortcut to the desired action, and exit IDE
2. Open settings directory: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519
3. Open a keymap XML file under "keymap" directory
4. Find the action changed in step 1, and change the "first-keystroke" parameter of the "keyboard-shortcut" node to "meta period". So it will look like:

```
<keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="meta period" />
```